# When deleting one post, delete all relevant posts

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook

I have following concept:

I have a frontend form with a custom field that saves the current slug each time a post is created on the frontend. Like following:

Post 1 has slug="1234"

when i am at Post 1 with slug 1234, i can create Post 2 with the embed form and "1234" will be saved in the custom field "custum-id-1" of Post 2.

now when deleting one of the Posts i want to get the slug of the current deleted post and search if any another post has the name of that slug as value in the custom-id-1 field and delete them as well. This means if Post 1234 was deleted, then Post 2 should also get deleted,  because the custom-id-1 of the Post 2 has saved the slug name of Post one.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: typically this is what you would use `foreign key constraints` for within a database - set `cascading delete` etc

Comment: delete from posts where custom-id-1='1234'; delete from posts where slug='1234';

Comment: Is it possible to show me an example in a function? Delete from posts where custum-id-1='1234' and delete from slug='1234'.  I am not developer and would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data is stored as integer/string in the post. You can add this code to query for the post where the post meta is equal to current delete candidate and then delete them iterating through the result.

```
<?php
add_action('before_delete_post', 'my_before_delete_post');
function my_before_delete_post($postid)
{
    $args  = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'post'
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'custum-id-1',
                'value' => get_post_field( 'post_name', $postid )
            )
        )
    );
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    // The Loop
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            wp_delete_post(get_the_ID());
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried to add the code you suggest but seems not to work maybe something is missing?
I am usung a custom post type called 'folder' so i changed the post_type to folder and the custom-field-1 to wpcf-secret-id-1 but still not working

Comment: I realized you are using post slug, not post ID. I have updated query to use post slug. please try now.

Comment: Yes! now its working as expected. Thank you very much. i appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

first off, depending on what database you are using you need to specify the "delete cascade" when creating a table

```
    ex:
    CREATE TABLE supplier
( supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) not null,
  contact_name varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);

CREATE TABLE products
( product_id numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
    FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
    REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

the products table is connected to the supplier table using a foreign key of supplier_id.
if you delete a record from supplier table, the corresponding products record with the same supplier_id will also be deleted.

```
ex.
delete from supplier where supplier_id = 1
```

the corresponding product record will automatically be deleted as well even if you only specify a delete from the supplier table.